# iOS: Random video from youtube channel?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, sdk, youtube

does someone know a way how to get a random video from a youtube channel in the ios sdk on iphone and ipad?

thank you!

Comment: thanks for the negative vote. reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a list of all of the videos in the channel, and then create a random number to select an index in this list.